# Should I use ServeMux or http directly in golang

Tags: http, go, mux

I was wondering if I should create a new ServeMux and register it to the `http.Server` or should I invoke `http.HandleFunc` and `http.Handler` directly?

I think the route with a ServeMux is better because `http.HandleFunc` obviously messes with the global state of the HTTP package, which is considered bad practice in Go. However, in many tutorials, even the official ones, I often see the `http.HandleFunc` route being used.

This makes me wonder: why should one use `http.HandleFunc` when there is a `ServeMux`? I know that ServeMux has some advantages (e.g. you can nest it without repeating the prefix all the time) but I wonder why I should ever choose `http.HandleFunc` over Multiplexer, especially since `HandleFunc` uses a `ServeMux` internally.

Edit: as promised in the comments, I've asked to deprecate the additional (and useless IMO functions) on [Golang-dev](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-dev) and they said no (well, on person said no). [Here is the link.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-dev/UOY45GtVp4I/XhIigo9OBwAJ)

Comment: (I also wanted to say that this is a good question, and a useful one for others in the future, since it has come up before)

Comment: elithrar: that's why I asked it here. I couldn't find anything on Google. Imo, `http.HandleFunc` and `http.Handle` should be deprecated, then. Using a `Mux` and `Server` only adds 2 more lines and ambiguity is always bad, especially if the more obvious way is the "bad way".

Comment: The Go1 compatibility promise doesn't allow removal, so we're 'stuck' with them until "2.0" (which is a long way off - years).

Comment: elithrar: I can't find anything about deprecation in the compatibility promise. It would still be available and work as it does now (at least until 2.0) but beginners will stay away from it.

Comment: The only way to deprecate is a documentation note. Go doesn't have the concept of "warnings" (from the compiler), so the effectiveness would be pretty minimal. You're welcome to propose adding documentation to these methods on golang-dev.

Comment: I will do! I think do a documentation note would do a lot! The first thing I did when I notice there are two methods was reading the docs again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're on the right track: you should prefer to instantiate your own `ServeMux`, for the reasons you've outlined.

Using `DefaultServeMux` also runs the risk of exposing profiling endpoints when using [`net/http/pprof`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/), since those are attached to the DefaultServeMux.

`http.Handle|HandleFunc` are convenience methods, and perhaps useful for keeping the boilerplate in example code down, but creating a ServeMux gives you the ability to wrap it, nest it within another, export it from a constructor, etc.